# How do I use the extension method Sum on a .NET list in F#?

Tags: list, f#, extension-methods

Suppose I have the following record type:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Store =
    {
        Products: List<Product>;
    }
    member this.TotalNumberOfItems =
        this.Products.Sum(fun p -> p.NumberInInventory)
```

I want to sum a count of total items in the store as in the method above, however the System.Collections.Generic.List extension methods don't seem to be available.  Intellisense does not show them.  How can I call Sum from F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to open the `System.Linq` namespace. For example:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq

type Product = { NumberInInventory : int; }

type Store =
    {
        Products: List<Product>;
    }
    member this.TotalNumberOfItems =
        this.Products.Sum(fun p -> p.NumberInInventory)
```

Comment: However, the idiomatic F# way of doing it would be with the Seq module: `this.Products |> Seq.sumBy (fun p -> p.NumberInInventory)`