# How do I call a C# extension method from F#, without open?

Tags: c#, f#, clr, extension-methods

I have an extension method in C#:

```
Foo(this Bar bar, int x)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

How do I call this in F#?

```
bar.Foo(100); // Doesn't work
bar.Namespace.Foo(100); // Doesn't work
```

---

The answer to [How do I use the extension method Sum on a .NET list in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286953/how-do-i-use-the-extension-method-sum-on-a-net-list-in-f) requires opening the module. Can I access the extension method without `open`?

Comment: You should be able to call it directly: `Namespace.Foo(bar, 100)`.

Comment: What lee said, or have an include with the namespace of the method

Comment: F# works exactly like C# in this regard, you need a `using Namespace` in C# too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is the same in F# and C#. To use an extension method, you either open the namespace (F#) or have a using statement for the namespace (C#), or you fully-qualify the method if for some reason you can't or don't want to open the namespace.

In both languages, with the `System.Linq` namespace open:

```
myArray.Sum()
```

In both languages, without the `System.Linq` namespace open:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(myArray)
```